# Check for password protected file with EPPlus ExcelPackage

Tags: c#, epplus, excelpackage

What is the correct way to check is an excel file is password protected (I do not know the password)? When I try to open it I get a non-specific exception ("A disk error occurred during a write operation.") that could be related to any other type of invalid file. Thanks

Comment: Share with us more about the exception, yor're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

If I try to open a password protected xlsx file, I get the exception -

> {"Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password"}

It also suggests using the overloaded method to open it

sample:

```
string mySpreadsheetName = @"path/to/file/name/xlsx";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(mySpreadsheetName);
ExcelPackage p1 = new ExcelPackage(fi, "abcd"); // this opens correctly, here "abcd" is the password
ExcelPackage p2 = new ExcelPackage(fi); //this throws an exception
```

Are you getting a different exception ?

Comment: yes, I'm getting "A disk error occurred during a write operation.". Also I do not know the password.

Comment: strange... can you share the exact line of code in which you are getting this exception ?

Comment: using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileStream))